# Returning a sliced list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am stuck on this question:

> Write a function `lossy_merge(list_1, list_2)` that returns a new list
>   containing all the elements of `list_1` except the last followed by all
>   the elements of `list_2` except the first.
>
> You may assume that both
>   `list_1` and `list_2` contain at least one element.

For example:

Testing the following:

```
ans = lossy_merge([10, 20, 30], [100, 200, 300])

print(ans)
```

Should give me: `[10, 20, 200, 300]`

The function I currently have:

```html
def lossy_merge(list_1, list_2):
    """returns list"""
    list1 = list_1[0:2]
    list2 = list_2[1:3]
    return list1 + list2
```

Gives me `[10,20,200,300]` however, when testing with other ones like:

```
ans = lossy_merge([10], ['rhubarb'])

print(ans)
```

I get `[10]` instead of the expected `[]`

What am I doing wrong?

Sorry, I'm new to Python 3 programming :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slice the first list up to but not including the last item, slice the second starting at the second item up to the end of the second list. Remember the last item is index -1 and the second item is index 1 because counting in Python starts at zero.

```
return list_a[:-1] + list_b[1:]
```